# "Can I offer you a hydrolysis tag?" It's delicious and essential to future spaceflight, but can we maintain such a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, tagging

The recent question  has added a [hydrolysis](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydrolysis) tag.

Below it I added the comment:

> I first removed the `hydrolysis` tag then after thinking further I rolled back my edit because "water-splitting" is going to be an important thing in the future of spaceflight whenever one needs to make rocket fuel or keep those pesky humans alive! It's right up there with CO2 splitting, but I don't know a fancy/general name for that. But if we're serious about maintaining the tag, it would probably have to be added to a lot older questions.

What do folks think?

**Question:** "Can I offer you a hydrolysis tag?" It's delicious and essential to future spaceflight, but can we maintain such a tag?

Comment: Other recently added single use tags: plasma-contactors static grapple lee

Answer (score 1):

Some context fore related tags.

There is currently no [electrolysis](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrolysis) tag, which currently has considerably more questions than [hydrolysis](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydrolysis) in general.

We already have the tags [hydrogen](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydrogen), [oxygen](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oxygen) and [water](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water), though they are a bit too generic. If [hydrolysis](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydrolysis) is to be used, a question about hydrolysis should use only [hydrolysis](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydrolysis) and not these.

The most relevant contexts for hydrolysis seems to be:

1. [life-support](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life-support)
2. [isru](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isru)
3. [colonization](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colonization)
4. [fuel-cell](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel-cell)

Arguably, [fuel-cell](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel-cell) already gives sufficient context by itself, while the others cases are more general.

I'm not against the idea, so if someone writes a proper tag usage and description, and tags some existing questions with it (and, potentially some of the other tags mentioned), that would be fine.
But the status quo isn't bad either, so I can't see there's any need to do anything quickly.